Why i cannot launch my app on the camera without it's func going nil
i cannot launch my app on the camera directly without everything going nil altough when i open it from my feed and go to camera it works fine.
i tried to simply set the tab on the one of my camera and kept the start running as they were
here it is where i set my tabview
struct BriefTabView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = 0

  CameraView(isShown: $showingCamera, cameraService: cameraService, selectedTab: $selectedTab)
                    .tabItem {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: selectedTab == 1 ? "camera.fill" : "camera")
                                .environment(\.symbolVariants, selectedTab == 1 ? .fill : .none)
                            Text("Camera")
                        }
                    }
                    .tag(1)
}

here it is where i set my cameraview
struct CameraView: View {
            .onAppear {
                cameraService.configure()
                self.observeKeyboardNotifications()

                

            }
            .onDisappear {
                cameraService.stopSessionRunning()
//                self.stopTimer()
            }
}

here is where i set my model for the camera
public class CameraService: NSObject, ObservableObject, Identifiable {

    func configure() {
        checkPermissions()
        sessionQueue.async {
            self.configureCaptureSession()
            self.session.startRunning()
        }
    }

    func configureSession() {
        sessionQueue.async {
            self.session.beginConfiguration()

            // Setup the video input
            guard let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .unspecified),
                  let videoDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice),
                  self.session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput) else {
                print("Could not create video device input.")
                self.session.commitConfiguration()
                return
            }
            self.session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
            self.videoDeviceInput = videoDeviceInput

            // Setup the photo output
            let photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            if self.session.canAddOutput(photoOutput) {
                self.session.addOutput(photoOutput)
                photoOutput.isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled = true
            } else {
                print("Could not add photo output to the session.")
                self.session.commitConfiguration()
                return
            }

            self.session.commitConfiguration()

            // Start the session on a background thread after a brief delay to ensure everything is set up
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                self.session.startRunning()
            }
        }
    }
  private func configCamera(_ camera: AVCaptureDevice?, _ config: @escaping (AVCaptureDevice) -> ()) {
        guard let device = camera else { return }
        
        sessionQueue.async { [device] in
            do {
                try device.lockForConfiguration()
            } catch {
                return
            }
            
            config(device)
            
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        }
    }
    
    //  MARK: Session Managment
    
    // Call this on the session queue.
    /// - Tag: ConfigureSession
    private func configureCaptureSession() {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            if AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualWideCamera, for: .video, position: .back) != nil {
//                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.hasDualWideCamera = true
                    self.zoomFactor = 2
                
//                }
            }
        }
        
        guard status == .unconfigured else {
            return
        }
        
        session.beginConfiguration()
        defer {
            session.commitConfiguration()
        }
        
        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
        session.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false
        
        let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(
            self.hasDualWideCamera ? .builtInDualWideCamera : .builtInWideAngleCamera,
            for: .video,
            position: .back)
        
        guard let camera = device else {
            set(error: .cameraUnavailable)
            status = .failed
            return
        }
                
        configCamera(camera) { device in
            device.videoZoomFactor = self.zoomFactor
            device.whiteBalanceMode = .continuousAutoWhiteBalance
        }
        
        do {
            let cameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera)
            if session.canAddInput(cameraInput) {
                session.addInput(cameraInput)
                self.videoDeviceInput = cameraInput
            } else {
                set(error: .cannotAddInput)
                status = .failed
                return
            }
        } catch {
            set(error: .createCaptureInput(error))
            status = .failed
            return
        }
        
        if session.canAddOutput(videoOutput) {
            session.addOutput(videoOutput)
            
            photoOutput.isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled = true
            
            videoOutput.videoSettings =
            [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
            let videoConnection = videoOutput.connection(with: .video)
            videoConnection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
            
            if (videoConnection?.isVideoStabilizationSupported)! {
                videoConnection?.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = AVCaptureVideoStabilizationMode.cinematic
            }
            
            session.addOutput(photoOutput)
            session.addOutput(metadataOutput)
            
            metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]
        } else {
            set(error: .cannotAddOutput)
            status = .failed
            return
        }
        
        status = .configured
    }

    



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
